# Regex in JS: find a string of numbers that are preceded by a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to locate a substring of numbers. This substring will begin with a period `.`.

Example string:
`myString = 12v3i$#@.789v10vvi4e9k` should return `789`.

My (very hacky) solution:

1. Find location of the period `.`
2. loop through each character that is next in string, if it is in [0-9], then add it to a string I'm building. If not, break the loop.

I'm very new to regex (assuming that is the right tool here), how can this be done with regex?

Comment: Here's [a good JS tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/you-dont-know-anything-about-regular-expressions-a-complete-guide--net-7869) if you've never used regex before.  [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) usually also worth a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var match = myString.match(/\.(\d+)/);
```

This will return array, where the first element is the whole match, and the second element contains the value of the first capture group (i.e. the digits).

I hope the expression is pretty straightforward, but nevertheless:

- `\.` matches a `.` literally (`.` is a special character in expressions, so it has to be escaped)
- `\d+` matches one or more digits

To learn about regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: close! I think you just forgot the [1] since this seems to return an array

Comment: No, I didn't forget it, I mention it in the explanation: *"This will return array, where the first element is the whole match, and the second element contains the value of the first capture group (i.e. the digits)."*. If there is no match at all, the return value will actually be `null`, so directly accessing the second element might result in a runtime error. Always check the result first.

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(/\.(\d+)/.exec("12v3i$#@.789v10vvi4e9k")[1]);
# 789
```

[RegEx Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eQ8fS1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wNLW3zHqRf08UHov)

`\.` will match the `.` character (since it has a special meaning in RegEx, we need to escape it with 
`\`), followed by 1 more digits `\d+`. We group only those numbers and get them in the output array with `[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
console.log("12v3i$#@.789v10vvi4e9k".match(/\.(\d+)/).pop());
```

`\.` matches literal `.`

and `\d+` matches on or more digits.